# How do I get the node URL in a Twig template?

Tags: theming, nodes, uri

I am trying to get the node URL in a Twig template. `{{ content.node_link }}` returns the full link, but I only need the URL.

How do I retrieve the node URL?

Comment: If you look in the node template, you will see that `url` is an available variable. Thus simply printing `{{ url }}` for example will render the raw URL, `/node/[nid]` i.e. `/node/30` without any wrapping markup. Is that what you are looking to do?

Answer (score 52):

According to [Functions - In Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates) you can use is simple by

```
 {{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}
```

Comment: This solution works, and is pretty groovy. But using {{ url }} in a `node--` based twig template will give you the same result.

Comment: I've used this in field template.

Answer (score 21):

In a node.html.twig you can directly use `{{ url }}`

```
<a href="{{ url }}">read more</a>
```

For more information read comment in core template : `/core/modules/node/templates/node.html.twig` :

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a node.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - node: The node entity with limited access to object properties and methods.
 * ...
 * - url: Direct URL of the current node.
 * ...
#}
...

<article{{ attributes }}>

  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
      <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}
```

Comment: You should explain your answer more rather than "simply put". An explanation, such as what @Danny Englander wrote in the question comment, helps the asker and others to learn more about *how* you came up with your answer and how they can help themselves in the future.

Comment: This is the easiest method, using a built-in variable in the node twig template.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 11):

I have found this solution that works, but is quite convoluted.

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': content['#node'].id()  }) }}
```

Comment: You can use `node.id` instead of `content['#node'].id()`

Comment: I am working in view with a display suite template and 'node' is not one of the available keys. {{ dump(_context|keys) }} gives these keys only: 'content','theme_hook_original','attributes','title_attributes','content_attributes','title_prefix','title_suffix','db_is_active','is_admin','logged_in','user','directory','settings','layout', '#cache','theme_hook_suggestions'

Comment: Great solution for display suite templates. @4k4 `content['#node'].id()` is correct for the DS context.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<a href="{{ url('<current>') }}">{{ 'Reload'|t }}</a>
```