# Get url of referenced entity in twig based on target_id

Tags: theming, entities

I have a content type with a field « referenced entity » called `field_suggestion_articles`.

User can choose related content and a view displays this list of related content at the bottom of the content. The views uses "content" (display mode, a template like teaser) and not fields.

[image]

I use a loop to display this list in `node--article--related-content.html.twig`:

```
{% for key,value in node.field_suggestion_articles.value %}
    {# display the title #}
    {{ content.field_suggestion_articles[key] }}

    {# display a text field #}
    {{node.field_suggestion_articles[key].entity.field_resume_suggestion_article.value|raw}}

{% endfor %}
```

But I don’t know how to get the node urls of these related content.

When I dump `node.field_suggestion_articles.value`, I get the `target_id` of the node so I guess I should use it to retrieve the url. But I’ve tried a lot of solutions found on Drupal forums and here on stackExchange but without success.

Could you point me in the right direction ?

Comment: something like this? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202609/how-do-i-get-the-node-url-in-a-twig-template so in your case `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.field_suggestion_articles[key].entity.id}) }}` should work i think

Comment: @Leigh It works ! I've already seen this answer butI didn't adapt it correctly. Could you post an answer ? I will accept it.

Comment: Rendering raw field values is unsafe. I would take a different approach. When you render the referenced entity in a view mode like teaser you get a second twig template specific to the referenced content type and this view mode, where you can render the fields of the children entity and also the url like Drupal does this for teasers out-of-the-box.

Comment: @4k4 Not sure to understand. You mean, I can use the native "link field" available in the view mode ?

Comment: Not a field, in a node template the url is provided in a variable `{{ url }}`.

Comment: @4k4 I've already tried this but it doesn't work in the loop. It displays the url of the main content and not the url of the related contents. How can I adapt `{{ url }}`in my loop `{% for key,value in node.field_suggestion_articles.value %}`?

Comment: @4k4I mention the native "link field" (read more) avalaible in display mode but I didn't manage to get it in the loop in the twig template.

Comment: You have to use a second node template, you are now in node--parent-content-type--parent-view-mode, but you have to print {{ url }} and the fields in node--child-content-type--child-view-mode. This solves a lot of problems you get otherwise, most importantly to avoid the unsafe `|raw` filter.

Comment: @4k4 I understand your explanation. However, I'm not sur how to proceed. I don't think I have a child content type and a child view mode. I have a content type "article" and a view mode "related content". Users choose some other articles as related content (same content type) when they edit an article. In my question, I already use `node--article--related-content.html.twig` where `{{ url }}` doesn't work. What would be the name of my child template ? Do I need to create an other content type for this ?

Comment: Of course you can reference the same content type, then only the view mode of the second template differs: `node--article--teaser.html.twig`

Comment: @4k4 Maybe I'm wrong but I think that it is what I am doing : the parent template is `node--article--full.html.twig` and the child template is 'node--article--related-content.html.twig'. And `{{ url }}`is not working here (it displays url of the current page/node). Do you see something wrong ?

Comment: No, this is not the child template because the `node` entity is the parent. Then you have two templates for the parent and not one for the child.

Comment: @4k4 ok so what would be the name of the child template ? Sorry, I'm confused here...

Comment: `node--article--teaser.html.twig` where `teaser` is the view mode you have configured in the parent view mode to render the reference field. In this case when it is the same content type you have to make sure that the child view mode doesn't contain the reference field so that you don't build an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

What they've done on this post should do the trick [How do I get the node URL in a Twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202609/how-do-i-get-the-node-url-in-a-twig-template)

So in your case this should work:

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.field_suggestion_articles[key].entity.id}) }}
```